# Permanent Misplaced View warning for Clip View in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

My application has a log window that displays lines in an NSTableView:

[image: Window > View > Bordered Scroll View - Table View > Clip View > Table View]

When I add auto layout constraints to the window no matter what I do I get a Misplaced View warning for the Clip View:

[image: Misplaced View warning]

I've tried updating its frame, updating its constraints, and resetting to suggested constraints, but nothing gets rid of the warning. The window displays and resizes correctly at runtime, and it doesn't even appear to be possible to add constraints to the Clip View itself.

I've pushed the code to github if you want to look at it in Xcode: https://github.com/MagerValp/AutoDMG/tree/e57b0140e3fc3f7f9e0d4550341ed249a6cf5378. The code requires the 10.10 SDK to compile, but the xib should be viewable in Xcode 5 and up.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue recently, warning about Clip view expected value is 17px larger than actual value.

I believe it is a bug of Xcode. And I do find a workaround to fix it(other than downgrading my OS to 10.9).

The solution is to edit the attributes of tableView in IB, disable "Headers". Don't show table headers and the warning will be magically gone. And we can guess that by default the table header is 17px :)

It's just a workaround, not an ideal solution. This is not our fault. The best solution is to wait for Apple to fix this Xcode bug.

Comment: Disabling Headers in the Table View indeed fixes the warning. Interesting find, but unfortunately I can't do that since I need to display the headers.

Answer (score 2):

Scrollviews' subview hierarchy are only sort of compatible with auto layout.

One way around this is to constrain the clip view so it is not bothering you. 
Then in the inspector, mark those constraints to be removed at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on how to constrain the clip view? It's not letting me add any constraints in IB.

Comment: Same here. All controls in the "Add New Constraints" popover for clip views are disabled.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 on 10.10. If I run Xcode 6.1 on 10.9 there is no warning.

Comment: Yeah they re disabled that in IB. You can still do it in code.

Comment: If you do it in code, how do you "mark those constraints to be removed at runtime"?

Comment: Any constraints added in IB  can be marked remove at runtime in the inspector. If created in code, all you need to do is have a reference to the ones you want to remove. A variable, an identifier string, or a container like an array containing it. In 10.10 and later you can disable a constraint without removing it.

Comment: What they are saying is that there is no way to *add* the constraints in the .xib editor in Xcode (aka IB). When you select the clip view, all the controls in the Xcode UI for adding constraints are disabled (I'm using Xcode 6.12.1 on OS X 10.10.1). And since you can't add them in Xcode, you can't prevent the build warning from occurring.

Comment: On the contrary. If you've give enough to let Xcode believe your document view is fully resolvable in the layout engine it will be quiet.

Answer (score 1):

> ScrollCiew
>
> > ClipCiew
> >
> > > TableView

If the error is coming from ClipView.
Check the ScrollView size, remember it.
And then click ScrollView as target, open up size inspector, enable Intrinsic Size using Placeholder with ScrollView size.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Xcode 12.3, the latest version of Xcode. But also have the same warning. I remove the misplaced view warning by change the TableView **Content Mode** from **View Based** to **Cell Based** and then the warning disappeared. And then I change back to **View Based**. The warning will never appeared again.