# XCode autolayout - is there an easier way?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I am trying to layout (essentially) a grid with two rows and five columns, so I have in the first row a label and a textbox, another label and a textbox, then a button. Same deal for the second row. I have tried on and off for weeks to get the darn thing to behave. What I see most definitely is NOT what I get when I run the application (OSX app, using XCode 6.1).

It says there are missing constraints, so I tell it to add them, which adds half a dozen more conflicting constraints, so I go through each one trying to fix them and just end up with a nightmare scenario where no matter what I do, it's never happy.

Is it possible to do what I used to do in the good old VB6 days, and that is to do something like this on startup?

label1.left = window.left + 10

text1.left = label1.left + 10

etc.

I cannot believe how horrendously difficult it is to just get it to show the controls where I see them at design time. I have no words to politely express my dismay and frustration here :-(

Comment: Grids are a little tedious with auto layout.

Comment: You haven't provided much in the way of how you are trying to set up the constraints. If it were me, I'd wrap each grid item in a view and set up the constraints for the objects inside that view (label, field) etc relative to that view. then you only need to add constraints between each of these grid views. Then you can do what you used to do in the "good old" VB6 days.

Comment: I'm not using a grid as such (if such exists), I'm simply adding labels, text boxes, and buttons on a form in a pattern resembling a grid and want them to stay where I put them.

Comment: My problem is the same as this, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957648/permanent-misplaced-view-warning-for-clip-view-in-nstableview

Comment: Even still, does anyone know how I might be able to specify the top/left/width/etc of my controls SIMPLY in a window's resize event? I can't continue this lottery I'm getting with auto layout "add missing constraints" and try to work from there. It's IMPOSSIBLE.