# Warning "Misplaced View" on Clip View

Tags: macos, compiler-warnings, finance

I started making a finance program yesterday. I didn't have internet, so I waited to search the problem up. I could not find anything that worked. I am using an NSTabView, and there are three tabs: income, assets, and net worth. Inside income, I have two NSTableViews. Inside assets, I have one NSTableView. The Clip Views in these three NSTableViews are not displaying. I have the newest version of Xcode (6.1.1), and am using Yosemite. There are also warnings that look like the following:

[image: Warnings for Misplaced View]

So if anyone knows about what might be happening or how to fix it, it would great if you could leave a comment or answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug for XCode 6.1 on 10.10. When running on 10.9, there is no such warning.

Here is a similar question: [Permanent Misplaced View warning for Clip View in NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957648/permanent-misplaced-view-warning-for-clip-view-in-nstableview)

I will Update this answer once I find a new solution other than downgrading my OS to 10.9.

**Update:**

I believe it is a bug of Xcode. And I do find a workaround to fix it(other than downgrading my OS to 10.9).

The solution is to edit the attributes of tableView in IB, disable "Headers". Don't show table headers and the warning will be magically gone. And we can guess that by default the table header is 17px :)

It's just a workaround, not an ideal solution. This is not our fault. The best solution is to wait for Apple to fix this Xcode bug.